# Error in `f()`: ! transformation for secondary axes must be monotonic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running into this error when trying to make a plot using ggplot.

```
Error in `f()`:
! transformation for secondary axes must be monotonic
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: In (vsmow + 1000)/(d18osw) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In log(al) : NaNs produced
```

Here is an example of the code I m running.

```
temp_function=function(x){
  vsmow=((x*1.03086)+30.86)
  al=((vsmow+1000)/(d18osw)+1000)
  temp= ((2.559*(10^6))/(1000*log(al))-0.715)
  temp2=((sqrt(temp))-273.15)
  return(temp2)
}

d18o= c(1.57250607,  1.80213529,  2.04688684,  2.05768980,  1.98708459,  1.34778009,  1.00992742,  0.49403459,  0.56191185,  0.19579498,
         0.08956884, -0.45381030, -0.60158300, -0.92339630, -1.24378840, -1.26242530, -1.08654800, -1.26757590, -1.55244220, -1.53874470,
         -1.11724190, -1.48195450, -1.42071900, -1.34024320, -1.02823520, -1.18611540, -0.70669460, -0.07921330,  0.62126673,  0.72444074,
          0.87499759,  0.90721387,  1.24767007,  1.21508923,  1.03826488,  1.04047116,  1.18316613,  1.08727293,  1.20401308,  1.09286830,
          1.06370239,  1.02918556,  1.02596777,  0.77820699,  0.80191575,  0.68288250,  0.41364236, 0.52444324,  0.42412122,  0.47631340,
          0.18180808,  0.24770451, -0.13031250, -0.29202420, -0.63853890, -0.75578190, -0.97535620, -0.94015680, -1.32330740, -1.25992660,
        -1.42660920, -1.63518900, -1.49774430, -1.74429840, -2.01900870, -1.56466740,  0.16242522,  1.01083316,  1.40150034, 1.32526660,
          1.30147320,  1.46371530,  1.28995767,  0.99914156,  1.01710591,  1.03839202,  0.98460735,  0.85265740,  0.66789528,  0.39425361,
         -0.32123960, -0.65520020, -1.19385120, -1.13205130, -1.12317560, -1.36345920, -1.56758210, -1.82638240, -1.89979770, -1.65500800,
         -1.62422980, -0.18052760,  1.01357724)
d18osw=c(0.29183729,  0.27975000,  0.10502778, -0.06572483,  0.17118316, -0.19654514, -0.06997483,  0.32036111, -0.13143750,  0.42998436,
          0.52024392,  0.56215365,  0.64008507,  0.41656163,  0.34580208,  0.52225087,  0.46624826,  0.31072483,  0.33935330,  0.26682292,
          0.70016768,  0.40168663, -0.20191667,  0.41197222,  0.24525257, -0.02140972,  0.47027628,  0.89164670,  0.77396007,  0.56274392,
           0.49325347,  0.33585665,  0.53992969,  0.16491146,  0.23636150,  0.34210183,  0.44513814,  0.46146701,  0.46509146,  0.48237162,
           0.43156944,  0.09048896,  0.09671962,  0.04099018,  0.50198958,  0.31100521,  0.05997069, -0.15857716,  0.76692962,  0.73520833,
           0.64020312,  0.61566233,  0.65118229,  0.77298611,  0.75675347,  0.55096351,  0.55380645,  0.56227947,  0.51668750,  0.53445486,
           0.37260069, 0.34081424,  0.40993576,  0.15124653,  0.30723284, -0.03553212,  0.36715538,  0.50027778,  0.50542795,  0.49255990,
           0.27760284,  0.08988271,  0.06961960,  0.48275673,  0.03034288,  0.53711111,  0.61154514,  0.65742448,  0.46065538, -0.51660851,
           0.16469010, -0.30371007,  0.60969817,  0.08988271, -0.41425000,  0.10897251,  0.08988271,  0.08988271,  0.16909337,  0.19873437,
           0.30460382, -0.04704174, -0.20544909)
samnum=seq(1,93,1)

df=as.data.frame(cbind(samnum,d18o))
colnames(df)=c("samnum","d18o")

dfplot=ggplot(df, aes(x=samnum)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  geom_point( aes(y=d18o,x=samnum),size =2.5)+
  scale_y_reverse(name = expression(paste(delta^'18','O (\u2030)')),breaks=c(-3,-1.5,0,1.5,3),
                  sec.axis = sec_axis(~temp_function(.),
                                                       name = "Temperature (\u00b0C)"))
```

I am trying to use the function to correlate `d18o` and `d18osw` to temperature. I'm not exactly sure how this is a non-monotonic transform. If I change the `d18osw` in the function to a single value, the problem goes away. I wish I could just use a single value but that's not the case.

Thank you

Edit

Here is the work around

```
 yaxis1 <- seq(2, -2, length.out = 50)
yaxis2 <- seq(10, 30, length.out = 50)

yaxis.lm <- lm(yaxis2 ~ yaxis1)
yaxis.lm$coefficients

df=as.data.frame(cbind(samnum,d18o))
colnames(df)=c("samnum","d18o")

dfplot=ggplot(df, aes(x=samnum)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  geom_point( aes(y=d18o,x=samnum),size =2.5)+
  scale_y_reverse(name = expression(paste(delta^'18','O (\u2030)')),breaks=c(-3,-1.5,0,1.5,3),
                  limits = c(2, -2),
                  sec.axis = sec_axis(~((.) * yaxis.lm$coefficients[2]) + yaxis.lm$coefficients[1],
                                                       name = "Temperature (\u00b0C)"))
dfplot
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect `temp_function` to do, but the code looks quite strange.  What it should do is take a vector `x` of any length and return a numeric vector of the same length.  Your function returns 93 values regardless of what I put into it (up to length 93; then it returns something the same length as x).

Comment: The issue I am having is not in the function itself but when using that function to make a second y axis.

Comment: The issue is that the function is inappropriate as an argument to `ggplot2::sec_axis` for the reasons described in my previous comment.

Comment: Figured out a work around but thank you for your help anyway

Comment: Please post your workaround as an answer to your question, in case someone else has a similar problem and needs a workaround.